# How can I access instance properties from within the object?

Tags: php, class, constructor

I am trying to instantiate a PHP class passing parameters to the constructor but when I print the data the values are empty.

The POST data passed to `configuracaoBancoDados.php` is received  without problems but when I create the `BancoDados class` from the `BancoDadosClass.php`, pass the parameters to the constructor and try to print this parameters using the `voltaValor() method` all the data is empty.

configuracaoBancoDados.php

```
<?php

include("../../../classes/BancoDadosClass.php");

if(isset($_POST["acao"]) && $_POST["acao"] == "criarBancoDados") {
  $host = $_POST["enderecoServidor"];
  $nomeBD = $_POST["nomeBD"];
  $prefixoTabelasBD = $_POST["prefixoTabelasBD"];
  $usuarioBD = $_POST["usuarioBD"];
  $senhaBD = $_POST["senhaBD"];

  $bancoDados = new BancoDados($host, $usuario, $senhaBD, $nomeBD, $prefixoTabelas);

  echo $bancoDados->voltaValor();

} else {
  echo "Ação não definida";
}

?>
```

BancoDadosClass.php

```
<?php

class BancoDados {

  var $host;
  var $usuario;
  var $senha;
  var $nomeBancoDados;
  var $prefixoTabelas;

  var $conexao;

  function __construct($hostBD, $usuarioBD, $senhaBD, $nomeBD, $prefixoTabelasBD) {

    $this->host = $hostBD;
    $this->usuario = $usuarioBD;
    $this->senha = $senhaBD;
    $this->nomeBancoDados = $nomeBD;
    $this->prefixoTabelas = $prefixoTabelasBD;
  }

  function voltaValor() {

    return "Dados: " . $host . " " . $nomeBancoDados . " " . $prefixoTabelas . " " . $usuario . " " . $senha;
  }

  function conectar() {

    $retorno = true;

    $this->conexao = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $senha);

    if(!$this->conexao) {
      $retorno = false;
    }

    return $retorno;
  }

  function desconectar() {

    mysqli_close($this->conexao);
  }
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: You need to use `$this->host`, etc. not just `$host` etc.

Comment: Plus, you should stop writing "PHP 4" code ... decide the visibility of your class properties! Seeing as some of them store database credentials, they should most likely not be public.

Comment: `var` is legacy since PHP 4. Use visibility instead, like `protected $host:` etc... You should also put visibility on your methods.

Comment: Please read up on http://www.phptherightway.com!

Comment: Ok. I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to print like this

```
function voltaValor() 
{
    return "Dados: " . $this->host . " " . $this->nomeBancoDados . " " . $this->prefixoTabelas . " " . $this->usuario . " " . $this->senha;
}
```

In order to access an *instance property* of an object from within the scope of the object, you need to use `$this->whateverTheNameOfTheVariable`.

For reference, see:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php